# Using Modifiers of Perl-compatible Regex (PCRE) in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

According to `grep --help` and `man grep`, we can use the `-P` option in order to interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, to be precise), instead of the default [POSIX basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE).

In Perl language, various **[Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)** can be added to the expression, in order to adjust the pattern interpretation (in the syntax of `/pattern/modifiers`).

So, **how can someone add modifiers** to the grep's Perl regular expression? I tried some variations like `grep -P "/^got.it$/ms" [FILE]` but the search results were wrong.

However, about the PCRE interpretation, the manual points out that:

> *This is highly experimental and **grep -P** may warn of unimplemented features.*

Is it possible that the grep tool **does not support modifiers at all**?

By the way, I noticed that one can perform case-insensitive pattern matching by using the `-i` option, which is an example of a modifier.

Comment: Crossposted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/410565/using-modifiers-of-perl-compatible-regex-pcre-in-grep ...which is okay, but you should indicate this!

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that PRCE compatible regexes aren't available in all versions of `grep`: The default POSIX non-gnu OpenBSD doesn't support these out of the box but GNU grep can be installed if you need to use PCRE `-P` feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PCRE's are not literally perl; they use a stand-alone C library, libpcre.  Sometimes "PCRE style" is also used to refer to, e.g., other languages which implement regexps using the same/similar patterns, even though they do not rely on libpcre (note `grep` *does* use the actual libpcre).

Strictly speaking, a regular expression doesn't really include modifiers,<sup>1</sup> it's just a pattern.  Some regexp *interfaces* (such as perl's) allow for the use of modifiers along with the patterns; `grep` doesn't.

There are [a few differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE#Differences_from_Perl) in terms of the pattern semantics too.  Again, keep in mind it's not actually perl, it's something based on it.

---

<sup>1. Unless they're actually [inside the pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), which you can do with `grep`.  E.g. `grep -P "(?i)foobar"` will be a case insensitive match.</sup>